# Activating ligatures with typescript in ConTeXt (MkIV)

Tags: context, ligatures

I've have the following example where i try to enable ligatures for the font [Kaffeesatz](http://www.yanone.de/typedesign/kaffeesatz/)

```
\definefontfeature[yanone-default][mode=node, kern=yes, liga=yes, dlig=yes]

\starttypescript [sans] [yanone]    
    \setups[font:fallback:sans]
    \definefontsynonym [Sans] [Yanone-Regular] [features=default]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [sans] [yanone]
    \definefontsynonym [Yanone-Regular][name:yanonekaffeesatzregular][features=yanone-default]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [yanone]
    \definetypeface [yanone][ss][sans][yanone][default]
\stoptypescript
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usetypescript  [sans] [yanone]
\setupbodyfont  [yanone,36pt]

\starttext

fi fl ff ffi ffl

\stoptext
```

The typesetting works, the font is used in the document but the ligatures are missing. 
Did i miss something important in the type-script or is

```
liga=yes
```

enough?

The [specimen](http://www.yanone.de/cgi-bin/download.pl?file=kaffeesatzpdf) of the font shows exactly those five ligatures shown above in the code.

The used ConTeXt version is:

```
mtx-context     | current version: 2012.04.19 23:18
```

Comment: The font has a broken `liga` feature, I don’t think it works anywhere.

Comment: I contacted the developer of the font and he confirmed the bug. Even on his system he doesn't get the ligatures. I don't know if/when he is willing to release a fixed version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code to fix the missing ligatures and a more complete typescript:

```
\startbuffer [yanone-feature]
lookup fligatures {
  lookupflag 0;
    sub \f \i    by \fi;
    sub \f \l    by \fl;
    sub \f \l    by \fl;
    sub \f \f \i by \ffi;
    sub \f \f \l by \ffl;

} fligatures;

feature liga {
  script DFLT;
    language dflt;
      lookup fligatures;
  script latn;
      language dflt;
      lookup fligatures;
} liga;
\stopbuffer
\savebuffer [yanone-feature]

\unprotect
\starttypescriptcollection [yanone]

  \starttypescript [\s!sans] [yanonesans] [\s!name]
    \setups[\s!font:\s!fallback:\s!sans]
    \definefontsynonym [\s!Sans]     [\s!name:yanonekaffeesatzregular] [\s!features=yanone]
    \definefontsynonym [\s!SansBold] [\s!name:yanonekaffeesatzbold]    [\s!features=yanone]
  \stoptypescript

  \starttypescript [\s!sans] [yanonesanslight] [\s!name]
    \setups[\s!font:\s!fallback:\s!sans]
    \definefontsynonym [\s!Sans]     [\s!name:yanonekaffeesatzlight]   [\s!features=yanone]
    \definefontsynonym [\s!SansBold] [\s!name:yanonekaffeesatzregular] [\s!features=yanone]
  \stoptypescript

  \starttypescript [\s!sans] [yanonesansthin] [\s!name]
    \setups[\s!font:\s!fallback:\s!sans]
    \definefontsynonym [\s!Sans]     [\s!name:yanonekaffeesatzthin]  [\s!features=yanone]
    \definefontsynonym [\s!SansBold] [\s!name:yanonekaffeesatzlight] [\s!features=yanone]
  \stoptypescript

  \starttypescript [yanone]
    \definetypeface [yanone] [\s!rm] [\s!serif] [modern]     [yanone]
    \definetypeface [yanone] [\s!ss] [\s!sans]  [yanonesans] [yanone]
    \definetypeface [yanone] [\s!tt] [\s!mono]  [modern]     [yanone]
    \definetypeface [yanone] [\s!mm] [\s!math]  [modern]     [yanone]
  \stoptypescript

  \starttypescript [yanonelight]
    \definetypeface [yanonelight] [\s!rm] [\s!serif] [modern]          [yanone]
    \definetypeface [yanonelight] [\s!ss] [\s!sans]  [yanonesanslight] [yanone]
    \definetypeface [yanonelight] [\s!tt] [\s!mono]  [modern]          [yanone]
    \definetypeface [yanonelight] [\s!mm] [\s!math]  [modern]          [yanone]
  \stoptypescript

  \starttypescript [yanonethin]
    \definetypeface [yanonethin] [\s!rm] [\s!serif] [modern]         [yanone]
    \definetypeface [yanonethin] [\s!ss] [\s!sans]  [yanonesansthin] [yanone]
    \definetypeface [yanonethin] [\s!tt] [\s!mono]  [modern]         [yanone]
    \definetypeface [yanonethin] [\s!mm] [\s!math]  [modern]         [yanone]
  \stoptypescript

\stoptypescriptcollection
\protect

\definefontfeature [yanone] [default] [featurefile=\jobname-yanone-feature.tmp]
\setupbodyfont [52pt]

\starttext

\switchtobodyfont [yanone, sans]
fi fl ff ffi ffl - -- ---

\switchtobodyfont [yanonelight, sans]
fi fl ff ffi ffl - -- ---

\switchtobodyfont [yanonethin, sans]
fi fl ff ffi ffl - -- ---

\stoptext
```

The `\startbuffer` code simply writes the content to a file. You can also take the content of the buffer and save it in an external file. The filename is passed to `featurefile`. This corrects the missing ligatures.

The rest is a normal typescript which takes into account that the Yanone-Kaffeesatz has three weights. I specified latin modern as fallback for math and monotype. You can/should change that and use the fonts you want to combine with Yanone-Kaffeesatz.

When you don't use the `\s!` shortcuts you can also remove the `\protect` and `\unprotect`. Here is how it looks like:

[image: result]