# Use .otf/.ttf in ConTeXt MKiV/LuaTeX

Tags: fonts, context, context-mkiv

I would like to use an .otf Font for my document which I typeset in ConTeXt MKiV. Sadly I was not able to change the font. I set `export OSFONTDIR="/usr/local/share/fonts;$HOME/.fonts` and ran `mtxrun --script fonts --reload`

To query the database worked fine for the fonts I have installed.

Where it comes to a halt are the typescripts. I use (at the begin of the same file as the rest of the document)

```
\starttypescript [sans] [delicious] 
  \definefontsynonym [sans]           [name:delicious]
\stoptypescript


\setupbodyfont[sans,rm,10pt]
```

And I only get the Computer Modern Font.

Sorry if the question is pretty noob-ish, but I did try several times with different fonts and read the Documentation in the [Wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Fonts_in_LuaTex) as well. But some examples I can't get to work and some state that the examples are outdated (e.g. [TypeScripts](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TypeScripts)). 
What would help me?

Comment: The easiest way is to use the simplefonts module: `\usemodule[simplefonts] \setmainfont[Delicious]`

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try, though I'd like to learn about the typescript way too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can use the simplefonts module, which is an easy way to get fonts working in ConTeXt. It's as simple as this:

```
\usemodule   [simplefonts]
\setmainfont [Delicious]
```

Or you can use typescripts, which is a more flexible way. Here is a very simple typescript:

```
\starttypescriptcollection [delicious]
  \starttypescript [sans] [delicious] [name]
    \setups[font:fallback:sans]
    \definefontsynonym [Sans]           [name:deliciousroman] [features=default]
    \definefontsynonym [SansBold]       [Sans]                [features=default]
    \definefontsynonym [SansItalic]     [Sans]                [features=default]
    \definefontsynonym [SansBoldItalic] [Sans]                [features=default]
  \stoptypescript

  \starttypescript [delicious]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [rm] [serif] [modern]    [default]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [ss] [sans]  [delicious] [default]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [tt] [mono]  [modern]    [default]
    \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [mm] [math]  [modern]    [default]
  \stoptypescript
\stoptypescriptcollection
```

Now you can use your font like this:

```
\setupbodyfont [delicious, sans]
\starttext  
  \input ward
\stoptext
```

For a more advanced typescript look at [my answer to the question “Activating ligatures with typescript in ConTeXt”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55967/5245). Also relevant might be the answer to [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51650/5245)

It is also a good idea to study the typescripts that come with the ConTeXt distrubution. The files are named `type-imp-<font>.mkiv`. It's not that hard to adapt one of those to your needs and you have something to start with.

Comment: For some reason, this script you provided did not work for me, but the one at http://wiki.contextgarden.net/exljbris_typescript did do the job.

Comment: Has `\setmainfont` been replaced with `\definefontfamily`? For example, `\definefontfamily[mf][serif][TeX Gyre Termes]`?