# Why can't I use some TrueType fonts in ConTeXt while others can?

Tags: fonts, context, truetype

Today, After reading the chapters about typography and fonts in the reference manual, I tried to define my own `typescript`. After `mtxrun --script fonts --reload`, I wrote the codes like this:

```
    % century.ttf in C:\Windows\Fonts
    \starttypescript[serif][centuryfont][name]
    \definefontsynonym[Serif][century]
    \stoptypescript
    \definetypeface[newfont][rm][serif][centuryfont][default]
    \setupbodyfont[newfont,12pt]
    \starttext
     ...
    \stoptext
```

It is so small, but only to test my usderstanding. When it succeeded, I changed the `century` in the third line to `palatinolinotyperoman` which could be searched by `mtxrun --script fonts --list --all --pattern=pala*`. Sadly, this font(pala.ttf) cannot be loaded.

I don't know why :-(

Comment: Have a look at: [Use .otf/.ttf in ConTeXt MKiV/LuaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58129/5245) If that does not help, please show the exact error message you get. Or try if directly loading the font with `\definedfont[file:century.ttf]` works.

Comment: @Marco, Now, it works if I define the synonym like `\definefontsynonym[Serif][name:palatinolinotyperoman]` rather than `\definefontsynonym[Serif][palatinolinotyperoman]`, though I still don't know the reason.

Comment: This is explained in [my answer to “How do I use a particular font”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51650/5245) section “How do I select the font?”