# How to use OTF files in ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, context

Is there a way For ConTeXt to use uninstalled .otf files in an arbitrary folder?

In my current LaTeX files, for example, I have:

```
\setmainfont{ProximaNova}[
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-RegularItalic,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
    Path=../../fonts/ProximaNova/,
    Extension=.otf]
```

It picks up the font files from a specific folder where I store all of my fonts. The naming is sometimes different between fonts so they are spec'ed in `setmainfont`.

The best I can tell from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58129/use-otf-ttf-in-context-mkiv-luatex) and [documentation](https://www.contextgarden.net/Simplefonts) is that ConTeXt needs to read the fonts from some `OSFONTDIR`, which can be more can one folder, but must be specified in this variable. I can't use just any .otf files, specified directly in the .tex file. Or am I misreading? I don't think I saw anything indicating that typescript can take paths to files?

Comment: While you may call fonts by file name, the font has to be in the font name database. The easiest approach is to have a script that runs mtxrun wirh appropriate parameters to update the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have the Proxima Nova font, but I just downloaded the [Cormorant](https://github.com/CatharsisFonts/Cormorant) font, so I'll use this one.  Then I use [`\definefontfamily`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definefontfamily) to set up the font.

```
\definefontfamily [mainface] [serif] [Latin Modern Roman]
                  [tf=file:Cormorant-Regular.ttf,
                   it=file:Cormorant-Italic.ttf,
                   bf=file:Cormorant-Bold.ttf,
                   bi=file:Cormorant-BoldItalic.ttf,
                   sc=file:CormorantSC-Regular.ttf]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [sans] [Latin Modern Sans]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [mono] [Latin Modern Mono] [features=none]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [math] [Latin Modern Math]
\setupbodyfont [mainface]

\starttext

\samplefile{knuth}

\stoptext
```

I could have hardcoded the complete file path but that is too unflexible in my opinion.  Instead I pass an appropriate value of `OSFONTDIR` to ConTeXt, as such

```
OSFONTDIR="~/Downloads/Cormorant_Install_v3.601/1. TrueType Font Files" context test.mkvi
```

[image]

Comment: @Roxy You can also define a typescript, which is actually my preferred way.  `\definefontfamily` is document in the Garden: https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definefontfamily

Comment: Thanks. If you are using new font files, why do the commands have to reference an unrelated font, i.e. Latin Modern Roman in your example?

Comment: @Roxy Fallback purposes.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to hardcode the path to the font file?

I tried:

`\definefontfamily [mainface] [serif] [My Font] [tf=file:./fonts/myfont.otf]` 

but that results in an error.